# Flutter refresh google map every time after come back from second screen

Tags: google-maps, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a HomeScreen which is StatefullWidget and incorporate Googlemap here, Over map multiple floating button like Notification, settings etc; Problem is that, when i am go to second screen like Notification and come to Home screen again, Every time map reloads & show black screen as well. Really its bothering me a lot. So how to solved or take control over reloading or not reloading and solved black screen issues??

Version:
environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.28+1

Comment: You should provide enough detail like code, platform you're testing on it, ... in your question

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?